# why is there a need for floating point standard to take care of decimal data and decimal arithmetic

Tags: numbers, system

Why is there a need to have a floating-point standards that can take care of decimal data and decimal arithmetic in addition to binary data and arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is information loss through rounding errors.

A decimal floating point standard will make it possible to represent `0.1` without information loss.

> Decimal floating-point (DFP) arithmetic refers to both a representation and operations on decimal floating-point numbers. Working directly with decimal (base-10) fractions can avoid the rounding errors that otherwise typically occur when converting between decimal fractions (common in human-entered data, such as measurements or financial information) and binary (base-2) fractions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point

For example take the number 0.1 in base10.
To represent this number in binary floating point is not possible with a finite number of bits, as it is infinitely long.

Run `0.2 + 0.1` in JavaScript. The output is `0.30000000000000004` because of the rounding error.

Here is also a page going into detail about this problem.

https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/